# How do I get @babel/parser to recognize 'undefined' as a special token?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm working on a project which involves examining the AST provided by @babel/parser, and in a certain (not super-rare) case it's not behaving as I expected. This line of Javascript:

`const var1 = undefined;`

when processed by this command:

```js
babelParser.parse(data, {
    plugins: [ `jsx`, `classProperties` ],
    sourceType: `unambiguous`,
});
```

gets transformed into this subtree:

```json
{
  "type": "VariableDeclarator", // expected
  "start": 240,
  "end": 256,
  "loc": {
    "start": {
      "line": 17,
      "column": 4
    },
    "end": {
      "line": 17,
      "column": 20
    }
  },
  "id": {
    "type": "Identifier", // also expected
    "start": 240,
    "end": 244,
    "loc": {
      "start": {
        "line": 17,
        "column": 4
      },
      "end": {
        "line": 17,
        "column": 8
      },
      "identifierName": "var1"
    },
    "name": "var1"
  },
  "init": {
    "type": "Identifier", // dang, really?
    "start": 247,
    "end": 256,
    "loc": {
      "start": {
        "line": 17,
        "column": 11
      },
      "end": {
        "line": 17,
        "column": 20
      },
      "identifierName": "undefined"
    },
    "name": "undefined"
  }
}
```

Why does the babel parser treat `undefined` as a variable instead of "UndefinedLiteral"?  (I mean, besides the fact that "UndefinedLiteral" doesn't seem to be a thing according to the [AST spec](https://github.com/babel/babylon/blob/master/ast/spec.md))

Is there a way to change the type of this initial-value node?  or will I have to add a special case to my code to look for `Identifier`s with a value of "undefined"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't because `undefined` is not a special token in the JS grammar. It is perfectly valid to do

```
var undefined = 4;
console.log(undefined); // logs 4
```

so you'll need to check for an `Identifier` called `undefined`, and if you want to be careful also analyse the scope of the variable to see if it is actually the global `undefined` binding, or a local one that could have some other value.

Comment: oh wow, I actually didn't know that.  very interesting, thank you, and point taken about checking the current scope.